# Get an ordered list of files in a folder

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I have used `boost::filesystem::directory_iterator` in order to get a list of all the available files into a given folder.

The problem is that I supposed this method would give me the files in alphabetical order, while the results seem pretty random.

Is there any fancy way of alphabetically sorting them?

My current code:

```
if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(myFolder)){
    // Iterate existing files
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_iter;
    for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dir_itr(myFolder);
        dir_itr!=end_iter; dir_itr++){

        boost::filesystem::path filePath;
        // Check if it is a file
        if(boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(dir_itr->status())){
            std::cout << "Reading file " << dir_itr->path().string() << std::cout;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not very fancy but it should work: put them in a vector and sort the vector.

Comment: The problem becomes worse when you need to sort them in a more complex way. For example: if you need to sort them based on some information in file headers you will have to open files one by one -> read header -> close file. Then, sort the files. Finally you will have to start another loop opening each file to read data records

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The fanciest way I've seen to perform what you want is straight from the `boost` [filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html) tutorial. In [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/example/tut4.cpp) particular example, the author appends the filename/directory to the vector and then utilizes a `std::sort` to ensure the data is in alphabetical order. Your code can easily be updated to use this same type of algorithm.

Comment: How to solve the 10 before the 2 (1, 10, 2, 3..) order problem?

Comment: @Pedro77 it's called natural sort. You need to write a sorting comparison function yourself. There are some on SO.

Answer (score 10):

> straight from the boost filesystem tutorial.

Thank you Tyler for the link.

If you are lazy, here is the adapted code:

```cpp
std::vector<std::filesystem::path> files_in_directory;
std::copy(std::filesystem::directory_iterator(myFolder), std::filesystem::directory_iterator(), std::back_inserter(files_in_directory));
std::sort(files_in_directory.begin(), files_in_directory.end());

for (const std::string& filename : files_in_directory) {
    std::cout << filename << std::endl; // printed in alphabetical order
}
```